# Unable to drag handles when editing feature

Tags: leaflet, leaflet.draw

I'm using leaflet-draw to draw and edit layers with the following configuration.

```
    window.drawnItems = new L.FeatureGroup().addTo(map);
        var options = {
        position: 'topleft',
        edit: {
             featureGroup: window.drawnItems
        },
        draw: {
            polyline: {
                shapeOptions: {
                    color: '#f357a1',
                    weight: 10
                },
                                guideLayers: guideLayers,
            },
            polygon: {
                allowIntersection: false, // Restricts shapes to simple polygons
                drawError: {
                    color: '#e1e100', 
                    message: 'You can\'t draw that!'
                },
                shapeOptions: {
                    color: '#bada55'
                }, 
                                guideLayers: guideLayers,
            },
                        marker: {
                                guideLayers: guideLayers,
                                snapVertices: false
                        },
            rectangle: false,
            circle: false,
            circlemarker: false,
        }
    };

map.addControl(new L.Control.Draw(options));
```

With this it's absolutely fine to add new features but when i'm trying to edit it, I mean change feature's geometry, when i'm dragging the handle (the white box) i'm moving the hole map instead of feature. So it seems like something prevents plugin's normal work. [image]

i'm also using

```
leaflet Snap "0.0.3"
leaflet": "^0.7.7",
leaflet-geometryutil": "*"
leaflet-draw": "^0.3.2"
```

Comment: Have you figured out the problem?

Comment: Yes, it's version conflict between plugins. I downgraded it somehow, now it's "leaflet-draw": "^1.0.2" and leaflet": "^0.7.7" and     "name": "leaflet-snap"   "version": "0.0.3",